# Joomla Multilanguage: Images not be load

Tags: apache, joomla

I set up my Joomla 3.x on a apache2 server. The files are located in the root folder of the apache(/var/www). Everything works fine, but know since i set up it with multilanguage support some of the images can't be load.

An url example of my page: http://www.example.com/en/widgetkit/slideshow

For example the button.png from the Widgetkit Slideshow:
Some of the images are defined in the slideshow itself(something like images/widgetkit/..../img.png). Joomla loads the image only when i change it to /images/widgetkit/..../img.png. That is because i pointed to the root of my apache.

My question now, is there a better solution to solve this problem, then put in all imagelinks(maybe files too) the / before?

Note: Some few images were load, but some not.

Answer (score 0):

try to use "base href" in the head section in the file index.php in the template directory

```
<base href="http://www.example.com">
```